# Warning "missing import statement" in Sails/WebStorm

Tags: sails.js, webstorm

I have the following code in the bootstrap.js in order to enable querying natively with waterline:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

sails.models.family.native(function (err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex({ location: '2dsphere' }, function ()
```

WebStorm always gives me a warning about `sails.models`, claiming there's a missing import statement. I do have Node.js core enabled in Settings. Why may this be?

Comment: Again not too sure what you're actually trying to accomplish here but I think, the bootstrap function is the first thing that instantiates, at this point the models have not been initialized so you can't yet access them?  Do yourself a favor and execute `console.log(sails)`, spend some time looking through it and seeing what all is there to access then, sails is node, if there is else anything that you need (e.g. npm modules) just require it as you normally would in node at the top of the file (be it controller/service/whatever) where it applies.

Comment: Again, I think I haven't explained myself well. The project runs perfectly; it's just WebStorm that gives an intellisense warning that it's not recognizing the module.